# How does my WCF Service communicates with my Winforms App Client?

Tags: winforms, wcf

I am currently developing a C# Windows Form Application that I intend to let it interact with a server. The server will receive posting from a mobile application that I have developed and whenever a posting is received, my Windows Form Application should be notified and give me a notification.

E.g. My mobile application sends an message over to my server. Once my server receives the message, my windows form application should display a new notification showing the content of the message received

The WCF Service has been done up in a seperate project file as I need the client to connect to the Service instead of hosting the service in my client project file. What I would like to ask is how does the service communicates directly with my winform app? Such as updating the UI of my winform app everytime a alert is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a [Publish Subscribe Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx#S6).  This will have your windows forms application act as a client to the server to subscribe for notifications, then act as a server to receive notifications as the mobile application posts come in.